# how to clear EGOImageView Cache.?

Tags: ios, caching, nsurlcache, egoimageview

Clear cache method of `EGOImageview` is not working.

Sample code is as follows.

```
[[EGOImageLoader sharedImageLoader] clearCacheForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:objNews.strImageurl]];
imgNewsLogo = nil;
[imgNewsLogo dealloc];
```

I am facing an issue once user change the image available on URL at server side with same name. I cannot see new image once its cached.
Is there any other way except `EGOImageView` where I can achieve this? or anything which I missed here?

Answer (score 0):

[[EGOCache globalCache] setData:connection.responseData forKey:key withTimeoutInterval:timeoutInterval];

set a suitable timeoutInterval.